# Can't seem to be able to size my order based on equity in TradingView

Tags: pine-script

No matter what I try I only receive a 'no data' message in the strategy tester, I tried many strategies like the default strategy below and nothing seemed to work including change the order size settings from the format window in the strategy tester or using these arguments

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © bankoflazarus

//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Works fine on TVC:DJI and the stocks we tried at all TFs. What symbol/TF are you running the strat on?

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF i ran it on NQ and ES futures

Comment: 5 min and 15 min timeframes

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF I just tried on DJI and it worked but still wouldn't work on NQ futures

Comment: User larger capital, like 1M instead of 100K.

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF yeah it worked, any reason as to why it worked with a larger capital?

Comment: Because the minis contracts are 20x the index.

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF Sorry for lengthening the discussion here but is there anyway for me to overcome this with a smaller capital amount since mini contracts are traded on margin and TV just disregards these margin requirements to enter trades and that doesn't help me that much with gauging the effectiveness of a strategy.

Comment: There are currently no provisions for handling leverage. Could be in the future.